# Does this measurement mean the IR sensor is broken?

Tags: gpio

My goal here is to make an IR sensor detect remote control signals. I wired up a 4.5 V IR sensor ([TSOP1556](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/mobile-pdf/300997/VishayTelefunken/TSOP1556.html)) like this (Leftmost side is the sensor pins, the numbers are Pi pins):

Gnd — 6 (ground)

Vs — 2 (5V)

Out — 1 kOhm — 12 (GPIO 18) — 1.2 kOhm — 6

Voltage between GND and OUT is 0.3 V. Does this mean the sensor is broken?

All tutorials demonstrating how to test a sensor with batteries and a LED had me believe that OUT should only be low when the sensor receives a signal.

### Update:

So, one proposed solution, if I understood @Milliways correctly:

Gnd — 6 (ground)

Vs — 2 (5V)

Out — 12 (GPIO 18) — 120 kOhm — 6

Which would theoretically give 3 V on OUT when taking into account the 80k internal sensor resistance. Probably safe to try?

[image: TSOP1556]

Comment: Why are you running it at 5V?  RPi is 3V3 so just run it at 3V3 same as the RPi.  The datasheet (not the link you posted.) shows no voltage divider for the OUT line and warns of pulling it low continuously which makes sense looking at the block diagram.  And yes, its active low.

Comment: @ChefFlambe Because as far as I can tell the data sheet (?) says 4.5 V minimum supply voltage. What's wrong with the link?

Comment: Ah, yeah you're correct about the 4.5V if it is in fact the older tsop1556.  I was looking at the latest datasheet from digikey as your link only allowed a 2 page preview then I'd have to download.  My bad.  However, are you sure its the TSOP 1556?  That's an older device (20 yr old?) and its been replaced by the TSOP 31556 which DOES have a supply range of 2.5V to 5.5V.  Its the same package and a few other tweaks, and they made the supply range wider, then added a 3 to the beginning of the product code to indicate the difference.

Comment: @ChefFlambe I'm pretty sure. I pulled it from an old Xbox DVD dongle.

Comment: @ChefFlambe About the 31556: how did you go about determining the name of the successor to, in this case, the 1556? Is there an easy way to do that? Also, I can't find 31556 on https://www.vishay.com/ir-receiver-modules/show-all/ — does that mean there's an even newer replacement? (I got a 34436 working, and learned the hard way that a 36 kHz receiver can't replace a 56 kHz one)

Comment: I was just looking at the latest data sheets at Digikey. The copyright dates at the bottom indicated that your original device was a very old device and then a search for that device on Digikey gave me the newest model that they carry.  Looking thru the product line-up showed that it was somewhat the same with a couple minor updates, like the CMOS/TTL ability. There could be an even more recent product but I didn't look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but one thing is **obvious** - connecting a 2.2kΩ resistor to the output is shorting the device and won't work.

It is unclear from the post what the device requires.

Comment: Thanks. I added the component name that I forgot to mention. What else could I add to make the question more clear? Also, is a voltage divider useless here then? I was hoping to be able to use a sensor that required more than 3.3 V.

Comment: Made some edits. Not sure if clearer.

Comment: The device appears to be a high impedance device with limited drive capability. I don't know the device or have the relevant data sheet. You COULD try a 120kΩ resistor to ground, but I would use a level shifter.

Comment: Certainly for testing I would just use a 50k resistor between OUT and the GPIO.  I wouldn't bother with the voltage divider (i.e. the other resistor to ground) as there are probably other resistors to ground on that line internal to the chip (and the maths is beyond me),

Comment: @joan Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but couldn't get it to work. It works fine with 5 V battery and LEDs though. I also have a TSOP1333 that works fine with a LED, but just can't get them to work with the Pi.

Comment: @Milliways I'm not very good at this so it took some time to understand the obvious part, but I updated the question with what I think you're suggesting. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Oh well, didn't work :-/